# Problem with "Update panel" control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax

i am using ASP.NET in which i am using Ajaxcontroltoolkit and "update panel" control for update part of the page.
it works fine first time when i run the program, but from second time the "update panel" control doesn't work. i can give more details about it, any idea what is the problem?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table border="1" id="tbRegistration" style="font-family: Calibri" width="800px">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 33%" align="center">
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbIndividual" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged"
                                Text="Individual" GroupName="Profile" AutoPostBack="true" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 33%" align="center">
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbAgent" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged"
                                Text="Agent" GroupName="Profile" AutoPostBack="true" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 33%" align="center">
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbBuilder" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged"
                                Text="Builder" GroupName="Profile" AutoPostBack="true" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: yes i meant so and i added code snippet please check. and i can't accept those answer which doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you have to use update panel in this way:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: can you please explain why 'conditional' and not 'always' (i read the MSND docs for this, but cant figure it out)

Comment: well i didn't use updatemode yet, but after using that my problem is not solved.

Comment: @Menahem see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925983/problem-with-update-panel-control/5933519#5933519

Answer (score 3):

if UpdateMode does't solve your problem try to use this :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false"  runat="server">

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Since the cool thing about the ASP.NET Ajax UpdatePanel is that its contents are updated asynchronously when an event that would normally generate a postback is raised inside, one would think that this is its default behavior.

But it's not: the UpdateMode property of the UpdatePanel has 2 possible values:

- Always
- Conditional

and the default value is Always.

When set to Always, the UpdatePanel is updated on every postback raised from anywhere in the page, so from controls inside the panel, inside other panels or just on the page.

When set to Conditional, the UpdatePanel will be updated only on postback originated by controls inside the panel or from the triggers specified.

So, if you have multiple update panels and you don't want to update all of them to be updated every time, you have to set the UpdateMode to Conditional